# Why is my code not updating on App Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have an App Engine Service, running on Google Cloud Platform.

I run an old version of my NodeJS application on it.

After having updated my code, I have run the following command: `gcloud app deploy`, in my GCP console, directly. It shows no error.

It says 'X files updated' and after that, I go on my application and the code is actually not updated.

I expect my code to be deployed and therefore, updated, after I run this command.

Why is this expectation not met?

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure you are deploying to the same version? If you're deploying a different version, did you migrate traffic to this new version? To check this, login to console.cloud.google.com > App Engine > Versions

   This will show you all the versions you currently have deployed and you can confirm which one(s) are serving traffic
2. You should also confirm that you actually have the 'updated' source code deployed. Following the link in bullet 1 above, you should see a column that says 'Diagnose' with 'TOOLS' under it. Click on the drop down and select 'source'. This will show you your source code. Confirm you have your updated code
3. If your files are static, they could be cached. You can try using cache bursting techniques (search Stackoverflow for this), or wait for some time and try again.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your attention and your time.
I did all that, but nothing worked.

However, when I check the sources, I can see that my code is the one I want to be so that leaves me even more clueless, because it still doesn't work. I have to precise that this very same code runs already perfectly on Azure.

Comment: Are your files cached? How many versions of your App do you see from the console?

Comment: I delete every old version to be sure of what I am seeing. Also I am sorry but I have no idea how to check if rather my files are cached or not. I 'flushed' the cache, in the memecache section...

Comment: The cache in memcache is for datastore. I'm referring to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref (search for cache)

Comment: I have no default_expiration key in my app.yaml unfortunately. Shoudln't that mean that files aren't cached or at least they should be flushed at some point?

Comment: yes. The documentation says it will have a default of 10 mins. Right now, I've run out of ideas. If I think of something, I will post

Comment: I thank you for your time and I sincerely appreciate your efforts.
Thank you mate.

Comment: Try this. Deploy to a different version e.g v2. Then access the url of this new version. Confirm it works as expected after which You can delete the old version and make this your default version.